# Azure postgres connection to powerApps

Tags: postgresql, azure, powerapps

My probleme is the postgre connector on powerApps doesnt allow to connect to an online server . Its mandatory to select a gateway and to create a gateway , but you have to do it in local (see the screenshot)  ?

I create a gateway on the `azure portal` and it doesnt appaer on the select option in powerapps. The only gateway who appear are the one on my local computer.
How can I create a connction between powerApps to my Azure PostGre database ?

I have try to use the SQL dataBase connector which allow us to use a cloud server but that doesnt work easer because it said the server doesnt exist or isn't found .

The screenshot of Postgres connector in PowerApps

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(reposting answer from MSDN Forums)

That is correct -- you need a Gateway to use the PostgreSQL connector today in PowerApps.  The reason we need a Gateway is because we need the user to install the PostgreSQL client for the connector to work.  We need some work to update our documentation to explain this requirement better.  PostgreSQL client: https://github.com/npgsql/Npgsql/releases

To understand more on PowerApps Gateway requirements, you can see this article here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/gateway-management

This article explains the on-premise Gateway in detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/gateway-reference

Also, for any PowerApps specific question, please feel free to leverage PowerApps community here: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1